# PHP - Speperate string into sections

Tags: php

I have a string:

```
2014-12-06 01:08:14 Andrew (76561198093241035) killed Moraiti () with weapon hgun_PDW2000_F
```

I need to be able to seperate this string into its seperate parts like so:

```
2014-12-06 01:08:14
Andrew
(76561198093241035)
Moraiti
hgun_PDW2000_F
```

The problem is I don't exactly how many characters each item will have. Is this even possible?

Comment: That's a little bit complicated if you don't have a 'blacklist' of words or something like that to detect where to split the string!

Comment: What would if I told you that it would always begin with a data timestamp like so `2014-12-06 01:08:14`

And `(76561198093241035)` would always be 19 characters long.

And the words `Killed` `with` `weapon` would never change

Comment: It would help do get the first string but not the other ones! because you need a pattern to detect/ say where to split the string!

Comment: Which parts of the string will allways be there?

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions:

```
$pat = '/^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) (.+?) (\((?:\d{17}|)\)) killed (.+?) (\((?:\d{17}|)\)) with weapon (.+)$/';
$str = '2014-12-06 01:08:14 Andrew (76561198093241035) killed Moraiti () with weapon hgun_PDW2000_F';
preg_match($pat, $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(91) "2014-12-06 01:08:14 Andrew (76561198093241035) killed Moraiti () with weapon hgun_PDW2000_F"
  [1]=>
  string(19) "2014-12-06 01:08:14"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "Andrew"
  [3]=>
  string(19) "(76561198093241035)"
  [4]=>
  string(7) "Moraiti"
  [5]=>
  string(2) "()"
  [6]=>
  string(14) "hgun_PDW2000_F"
}
```

Comment: If match failed then `$matches` would be an empty array, not NULL. Can you post the string that failed?

Comment: Never mind, I was trying to pass in an array of strings.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `explode` to convert the string into an array. With the string you specified, you would use a space as the delimiter and then you could get the various elements of the array.

Example:

```
$str = '2014-12-06 01:08:14 Andrew (76561198093241035) killed Moraiti () with weapon hgun_PDW2000_F';
$array = explode(' ', $str);

echo $array[0].' '.$array[1].PHP_EOL;
echo $array[2].PHP_EOL;
echo $array[3].PHP_EOL;
echo $array[5].PHP_EOL;
echo $array[9].PHP_EOL;
```

Result:

> 2014-12-06 01:08:14
>
> Andrew
>
> (76561198093241035)
>
> Moraiti
>
> hgun_PDW2000_F

If you want to use other parts of the array, use `var_dump($array);` to figure out which ones,